# How to pass redux store in react native between pages?

Tags: react-native, react-redux

In react native app I have 2 pages. If I upload a redux store with data on the 2 page, then return to the 1 page - how can I access the store with the uploaded data from the 2 page? So is there a way to access the store with data from all of the pages in react native?
Maybe simoke example or where to read?
Thanks

```
   1page.js 
    class ScreenHome extends Component{

        static navigationOptions = {
            title: 'ScreenHome',
        };
        constructor(props){
            super(props)
            console.log("PROPS: ",props);
        }
        render() {
            const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
            return (
                <View>
                    <Button
                        title="Go to load data page"
                        onPress={() => navigate('New', { name: 'Jane' })}
                    />
                    <Button
                        title="Get redux data"
                        onPress={() => {console.log(this.props)}}
                    />
                </View>
            );
        }
    }

    class ScreenRegister extends Component{
        static navigationOptions = {
            title: 'ScreenRegister',
        };
        render(){
            return <Text>ScreenRegister</Text>
        }
    }
    const MainScreenNavigator = DrawerNavigator({
        Recent: {
            screen: ScreenHome
        },
        All: {
            screen: ScreenRegister
        },
    });
    export default SimpleApp = StackNavigator({
        Home: {
            screen: MainScreenNavigator
        },
        Chat: {
            screen: ScreenHome
        },
        New: {
            screen: testScreen
        }
    });
    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    const {items, isFetching, done} = state.myTestData
    return {testScreen:{items, isFetching, done}};
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        getNewItems: () => {
            dispatch(fetchData());
        }
    }
}

export default someTest = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(SimpleApp)



    2page.js
        class testScreen extends Component{
            static navigationOptions = {
                title: 'testScreen.js',
            };


            _reduxStuff = () => {
                this.props.getNewItems();
            }
            render() {
                const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
                const {done, items, isFetching} = this.props.testScreen;
                return (
                    <View>
                        <Text>Some new screen</Text>
                        <Button
                            title="Load Data"
                            onPress={() => this._reduxStuff()}
                        />
                    </View>
                );
            }
        }

        const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
            const {items, isFetching, done} = state.myTestData
            return {testScreen:{items, isFetching, done}};
        }

        const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
            return {
                    getNewItems: () => {
                        dispatch(fetchData());
                    }
            }
        }

        export default FilterLink = connect(
            mapStateToProps,
            mapDispatchToProps
        )(testScreen)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be a container for each page, a store for data you want to access between pages and actions to changing this store. By using `mapStateToProps` you can pass this store to the container of the page. You can find good example in [here](https://github.com/uiheros/react-native-redux-todo-list).

Comment: Thanks. I have added a connect container for each page, but don't get my store on the 1st page, but everything is ok on the next pages. Is there any issues with the StackNavigator and Redux?

Comment: There isn't any issue. Maybe it's about your code in container or reducer. check it if the container get the store state or not. If it's not check reducer.

Answer (score 1):

On your first container you'll need to make your async calls to fill your store.

You can do a dispatch on your `componentWillMount()` and populate your store with the received data.